# Redirecting even absolute url with mode rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

i am trying to implement pretty url.
Everything i have written in PHP and it works properly. I need to handle every request by index.php.

For example website.com/page/search/question/dogs will be handled by index.
BUT website.com/templates/header.tpl will start downloading the file.

I want to handle by index.php even adress to another file.

In .htaccess i have.

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

How can i hande even absolute url to file by index.php?

Comment: What do you mean Henry? Can you explain what the term "Redirect" means in your question?

Comment: I mean user type adress "example.com/hello.php" but server will not call hello.php but index.php (and params after .php ?id= /page/view will be avaible for index.php)

Comment: Where should the value of the `?id` parameter come from?

Comment: I have better example. As i have wrote in question. When user call website.com/templates/header.tpl i dont want server to respond by giving the header.tpl to download. But i want server to call index.php for handling the request. Other things i will do in PHP but i want to redirect ALL requests to index.php

Comment: Is your quesiton that: *.tpl cant be redirected to index.php? or any thing else?

Comment: not just .tpl but all file requests .tpl .txt .* and example.com/page/home too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rewrite URLs for files that exist on the server already, you need to drop the `!-F` (not a file) and the `!-D` (not a directory) check. Otherwise you've setup the wrong `RewriteCond`itions for your `RewriteRule`.

However, there is one caveat, you don't want to rewrite for `index.php` itself, otherwise it would result in an endless rewrite-loop.

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=^./index\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php [L]
```

See as well [`RewriteCond` Directive<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Answer (score 0):

rmove the conditions that the url must not be a directory or a filename:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: I've tried it before, but it will throw error 500 Internal Server Error